# Minimal latex installation broken after upgrade

Tags: latex

I had MacOS 12 with basic tex installed (from here https://tug.org/mactex/ ). I basically only need to convert tex files (using several basic packages) to pdf and the `texi2pdf` command-line tool was perfect for that (no need to download 5GiB of files I'm never going to use).

However after upgrade to MacOS 13 the `texi2pdf` binary disappeared and reinstalling basic tex does not re-create it (using find over the entire drive returns no results for `texi2pdf`). Has anyone had such an issue?

Comment: It appears that the binaries distributed as part of basic tex have changed in the meantime. I can generate pdf documents from tex using pdflatex.

Comment: texi2pdf is used to convert Texinfo files into PDF.